# Flutter error with Blend mode, change for solid color

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I have a image button in a container and for the background I use a blend mode.overlay, but when I refresh the widget the blend mode fail and show just the solid color.
I can't understand what happend or how can fix it. Can anyone showme the way?

this my boxDecoration code:

```
BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(radius)),
        color: color,
        backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.overlay,
    );
```

Here a example of my bug:
[Correct state when create a widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pF8w.png)
[Wrong state after refresh widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM3b3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Flutter Inspector to find out exactly what is causing the problem ... just look at the properties set.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/inspector
https://youtu.be/CcLfGJZS8ns

It will also help if you post the full code of the widget here.
It probably has something to do with the `build()` method.